# How to check database collections in MEAN stack

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack

I am using an Ubuntu OS 14.04. I have installed all requirements for MEAN stack project. Referring this website [click here](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/12/09/mean-stack-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial#server)

And the above explained example is working for me but I want to check the database collections

Please tell me the right way of using mongodb in Ubuntu. I am new in MEAN stack

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may start the Mongo DB server by running "sudo service mongod start". 
After that you may open a new terminal and type "mongo" and that should connect to mongo db server by showing "connecting to test".

```
use following commands: 

-> "show dbs" - show existing database.
-> "use db_name" - to switch to a particular database.
-> "show collections" - to show all the collections in the selected database
```

Am not very sure about this and if this fails, you can download and use MongoDB GUIs like Mongo Management Studio or Mongo Booster or RoboMongo.